# Cant get a value of variable from Database cause its outside the boundry of array

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I am trying to get systemRec through my database. I have 2 modes for my system Trace or Sim. I have no problem getting the data for my trace but for sim, I get the error "Index is outside the bounds of array" This is my code. I'm getting my newSystemRec from another file by the name of datalayer.cs 
This is a pic of my Database.[image]

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        InitializeP2Trace();           
        dataLayer.InsertHandler(this.Handle);
        Args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(EmsJump);
        this.dgComp.Style.VerticalAlignment = C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.AlignVertEnum.Center;
        this.dgSchematic.Style.VerticalAlignment = C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.AlignVertEnum.Center;
        dgSchematic.Splits[0].ColumnCaptionHeight = 28;
        dgComp.Splits[0].ColumnCaptionHeight = 28;
        xmlPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "temp.xml");
        tsMarkup.Location = new Point(355, 0);
        if (Args != null)
            mi.Invoke();
    }
    private void wordSearch_SystemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 newSystemRec = dataLayer.GetSystemType(p2Trace.FileName, p2pMode);
        newSystemRec--;
        Int32 index = newSystemRec;
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                systemMode = SystemMode.Hydraulic;
                cbSystem.SelectedIndex = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                systemMode = SystemMode.Pneumatic;
                cbSystem.SelectedIndex = 2;
                break;
            case 0:
            default:
                systemMode = SystemMode.Electrical;
                cbSystem.SelectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
        if (p2pMode == p2p.Trace)
            tabP2Trace.TabVisible = true;
    }
```

This part is where I'm calling my newSystemRec and It goes to datalayer.cs to get my systemRec, where i get error.

```
 class DataLayer
 {
    private string currentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    private OleDbConnection cn;       
    private int fileRec;
    private string path, appPath;
    private Dictionary<Int32, String> standardTypes;
    public event EventHandler<FileNameEventArgs> UpdateFileName;
    private OleDbConnectionStringBuilder sb;
    private String connString;
    private DataSet ds;   

    public Int32 GetSystemType(String fileName, p2p p2pMode)
    {
        LoadSystems();
        DataRow dr;
        Int32 systemRec;
        if (p2pMode == p2p.Trace)
        {
            dr = ds.Tables["Files"].Select(String.Format("FileName = '{0}'", fileName))[0];
            systemRec = dr.Field<Int32>("SystemRec");
        }
        else
        {
            LoadSimTable();
            dr = ds.Tables["p2Sim"].Select(String.Format("FileName = '{0}'", fileName))[0];   //Here i get the error
            systemRec = dr.Field<Int32>("SystemRec");
        }
        return systemRec;
    }
```

Comment: Well do you *have* any values matching that filename? If not, `Select` won't find any rows, hence the exception...

Comment: -yes, I do have the same fileName in the database, I don't have problem when the p2pMode == p2p.Trace. my problem is in else part.

Comment: But do you have any values matching that filename *in the p2Sim table*? That's the point. Your current code *assumes* that you do, and it looks to me like that assumption isn't valid in this case.

Comment: -I upload a pic of my database. As much I notice I have all the names matching.

Comment: Well given that we don't know the value of `fileName`, that doesn't really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet so how can i know what is the value of my fileName?

Comment: Well you could use a debugger, or log it somewhere... debugging is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: I get null for fileName. I don't know why